# Why is firebase recycler adapter returning null

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am really stuck here, I need to get the Post class value that is held in `users/user_id/latest_post` only some users have this value. so I thought:

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("latest_post")) {
                Post latest = dataSnapshot.child("latest_post").getValue(Post.class);
                latest_posts = latest;
                post = latest;
            }
        }
```

should work, it does in getting me the values and ignoring the ones that don't contain a latest_posts child. But my recycler adapter and view-holder doesn't seem to use this and when I try setting up the recycler view is says the value it's trying to get is null.

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostHolder postHolder, int position, @NonNull Post post) {
            postHolder.setPost(post);
        }

        @Override
        public PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_content, parent, false);

            return new PostHolder(view);
        }
    };
```

Here is the rest of the firebase adapter ^ and then here is the setPost function:

```
 void setPost(Post post) {

         String key = post.getPost_id();
         Integer reads = post.getReads();
         String titleString = post.getTitle();
         String bodyString = post.getBody();
         String usernameString = post.getAuthor();
         String category = post.getCategory();

        System.out.println("setPost " + usernameString);
...
}
```

Top of file I am holding:
    Post post;

which is updated with the values in the childEventListener. Any ideas where I am messing up? Thank you.

UPDATE:

I have made these changes using my User class which contains the Post class (latest_post):

```
 void setupRecycler(Query query) {

    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("users");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
            .setQuery(query, User.class)
            .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, PostHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostHolder postHolder, int position, @NonNull User user) {

            if (user.getLatest_post().getAuthor() != null) {
                postHolder.setPost(user);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_content, parent, false);

            return new PostHolder(view);
        }
    };


}
```

Now I am trying to filter when the setPost(user) is called so it only lets through if the latest_posts value is not null. But I must be misunderstanding something, because it gives me the first two names but still attempts to use the vaues which dont have latest_post which results in crashing due to null.

UPDATE 2:

Getting closer, this works:

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("users").orderByChild("latest_post");
```

I'm guessing because it orders them by the users that have latest_post, but it crashes if I scroll to the bottom because Then all the rest are still there, so it attempts to set a string value to a textView when it is null. How do I exclude these pesky things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because you can't filter a query to exclude posts that do not exist, and you do not have access to the list that `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses. The only solution to accurately and safely filter the data the way I needed was to use a custom recyclerView Adapter, and a list of my class, and filter and order the list as needed after the query.